# Why can I see the password of a PasswordBox in Snoop?

Tags: c#, wpf, passwordbox

I am trying to understand how does PasswordBox protect the reading of the password from an external application. And what I don't understand is how come I have the capacity to read the password of my WPF window with Snoop :

[image]

I thought this was the kind of breach that PasswordBox was supposed to solve.

Comment: AFAIK,this is a general behavior.You don't need to worry about that

Comment: Well, more or less you  do not need to worry. Password is stored in memory as a `SecureString`, not a big step in security but better than nothing (at least it won't stay in memory when no longer needed). For simplicity (because many/most APIs want a `string`) when you read `Password` property you create a `String` with that password. Now, that string is subject to normal GC and memory content won't be cleaned then it's possibly available. If you're concerned about security then don't use `Password` property

Comment: and use `SecurePassword` instead (which returns a copy of the password as `SecureString`, which will be zeroed when not GCed).

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'm still discovering how all of this work together.

Comment: Obviously an application with the required privileges can access your app and read its content (you can't really stop this), it may even install a keyboard hook to record all keystrokes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be useable - at one point or another - the password must be in memory as a clear string and/or must be retreivable as a clear string. SecureString and PasswordBox limit that time of vulnerability. But they can not get rid of it. It can do stuff like force agressive collection by the GC, prevent Optimsiations like String itnerning and even overwriting the memory with random data the moment it runs out of scope.

The Passwrod property is how you retrieve said naked string. And snoop can apparently query it just like your code can.

Personally I think that if an attacker can read your memory, you pretty much lost the Security Battle already. If you got a encrypted value in memory, you propably have the key there too. Together with the code actually working on both. So it is not like an attacker could not decrypt it the same way you would. The task is a bit more complex, but that is it.

The vulnerability to memory reads is why [Heartbleed](https://xkcd.com/1354/) was such a huge thing. You have to blindly trust the RAM. Because if it is compromised, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: "Personally I think that if an attacker can read your memory, you pretty much lost the Security Battle already." Unfortunately our worries come from inside the project between collaborators. But thank you, this is what I was trying to understand.

Comment: @MohammedLarabi if you can't trust your own code then things are much more complicate. You may run those "low trust" plugins in a separate **sandboxed AppDomain** with lower privileges (= a subset of safe permissions). If you want a higher degree of separation then you have to split your application in separate components which run in isolation (I'm thinking about **Docker**, just to mention the first solution that came to my mind but they might also be separate processes running with low privileges Windows user).

Comment: Oh, well...of course there is a price to pay for this. It might be in deployment complexity (because of Docker and/or Windows users) and in every case in performance because calls and data transfer need to go across process boundaries, even in the best case (shared memory, when applicable) you still have some overhead.